# SpriteKit scene in a single view application?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm creating a minigame app on Xcode, using the single view app format. However, I'm hoping to add a brick-laying game in one of the Views- which would greatly benefit from the physics features in SpriteKit. I have tried using this code from a previous question asked on here, implementing my own scene:

```
let scene = Brick(fileNamed: "Brick")
scene?.scaleMode = .aspectFill
self.view?.presentScene(scene!, transition: SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.42))
```

This gives me an error that UIKit does not contain the method of ".presentScene" no matter how many imports I add.
I have also tried to use the SpriteKit View but I am honestly not sure how it works and Google isn't helping.
TLDR: How do I put a SpriteKit Scene minigame in a single view app using ViewControllers and segues etc??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're in a regular `UIViewController`, then your `view` is of type `UIView` and it, indeed, doesn't know about the `presentScene` method, which is part of `SKView`. You have to use an `SKView` for presenting your scene.

Assuming you want to add one and have it be the size of your view controller's view:

```
let scene = Brick(fileNamed: "Brick")!
scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
let skView = SKView(frame: view.frame)
view.addSubview(skView)
skView.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.42))
```

Or use Interface Builder to add an `SKView` to your view controller UI, then connect it with an `IBOutlet`.